# Android prints <br> after HTML.fromHTML

Tags: android

I'm using Wordpress API to get posts in my app. I'm trying to add new line while writing a post. However when I ,for example, add post like this :

*THIS IS /n a POST*

In my app I can see /n in the textView exactly as I put it above. The same thing is happening when I try to use `<br>` tag.

Setting post in textView:

```
String content = String.valueOf(HTML.fromHTML(p.excerpt));
vItem.shortContent.setText(content);
```

Why is that ?

EDIT!!!

It's working after adding :

```
String content = p.excerpt.replace("\\n","<br>);
vItem.short_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, well, but that doesn't formats the HTML code. I mean, this is only showing normal text, it isn't?

Comment: It is formatting HTML code :) I add "\n" in post content and then replace it with <br>

Comment: Great, glad to hear it's working for you!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `p.excerpt` is an HTML `String`, use

```
vItem.shortContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(p.excerpt));
```

instead.

You are seeing the new lines because `String.valueOf(Object)` calls `toString()` from the param object. Since Html.fromHtml() returns an `Spannable`, your code is doing a `spannable.toString()` so its returning the literal text.

Comment: I edited, did you tried HTML.fromHTML or Html.fromHtml? It's not the same.

Comment: I tried Html.fromHtml ... still can see \n or even <br> in textView :/

Comment: It's working now :) I eddited the post. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also put the html formated text in the string resources directory as follows

```
 <string name="helloworld">
 <![CDATA[

    This is now formatted:<br />
    <strong>Hello world</strong> - this should work fine
]]>

</string>
```

you can then call the string in your activity as follows

```
 txtView = findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    String formatedstring = getString(R.string.helloworld);
    Spanned txt = Html.fromHtml(formatedstring);
      txtView.setText(txt);
```